# What happened when open a child Winform triggered all form re-calculate autoscalemode DPI

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform `FrmTaskDtl`, autoscalemode is DPI. This form has the event as following:

```
private void FrmTaskDetail_Shown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!dataLoaded)
    {
        LoadCurrentData(); // 加载数据
        dataLoaded = true;
    }
}

private void LoadCurrentData()
{
    DataReadingTask ReadingTask = new DataReadingTask();
    ReadingTask.MethodTaskList(paraMeterTaskNum);
    txtTaskNum.Text = ReadingTask.iTaskNum;
    txtTaskClass.Text = ReadingTask.iTaskType;
    txtTaskName.Text = ReadingTask.iTaskName;
    txtTaskDescription.Text = ReadingTask.iTaskDescription;
    txtPublisher.Text = ReadingTask.iLaunchID;
    txtLaunchDate.Text = ReadingTask.iLaunchDate;
}
```

Now the problem is: when I open the form, all forms shrink to 100% (currently my primary monitor scaling has been set to 125%). In the meanwhile, all desktop icons are not scaled. When I set my primary monitor scaling to 100%, this phenomenon disappears. What happened?

I have tried add this code into shown event:

```
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None;
```

The problem still persists.

How to avoid this from happening?